# can not reduce size of h tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I download bootstrap theme which contain

```
<!-- Top Bar Start -->
        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="logo">
                                <h1> ***change this tag size*** </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="top-bar-right">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h2>+123 456 7890</h2>
                                <p>Call Us For Free Consultation</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Top Bar End -->
```

and the css:

```
.top-bar .logo h1 {
margin: 0;
color: #9166;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 55px;
font-weight: 800;
```

}

but as I define font-size in .top-bar .logo h1, it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean ' it doesn't work '  ? Does it get added to the element ? did you inspect the dev console to see what happens ? is the style crossed off ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```css
.top-bar .logo h1 {
margin: 0;
color: #9166;
font-size: 25px!important;
line-height: 55px;
font-weight: 800;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see an issue with nesting in CSS that really should be avoided, as it just puts confusion in the stylesheet.

Instead of typing this

```
.top-bar .logo h1 {
   margin: 0;
   color: #9166;
   font-size: 25px;
   line-height: 55px;
   font-weight: 800;
}
```

type this

```
.logo-script {
   margin: 0;
   color: #9166;
   font-size: 25px;
   line-height: 55px;
   font-weight: 800;
}
```

and then append to your h1 element this  `class="logo-script"`
so it-s result will be this

`<h1  class="logo-script"> ***change this tag size*** </h1>`

This will remove some confusion and add your wanted style to the H1

Here is a demo of the problem solved, that works [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6dfzwkob/)

Answer (score -1):

for bs you should use **important**
try this

```
.top-bar .logo h1 {
margin: 0;
color: #9166;
font-size: 25px; !important
line-height: 55px;
font-weight: 800;
```